# slapd does not start after reinstallation

Tags: linux, centos-7, openldap

I am fighting the third day with OpenLDAP to add the first organizational unit. I decided to start over and delete all my attempts:

```
systemctl stop slapd
systemctl disable slapd
yum -y remove openldap-servers openldap-clients 
rm -rf /var/lib/ldap
userdel ldap
rm -rf /etc/openldap
```

Then install it again

```
yum -y install openldap-clients openldap-servers-2.4.44
systemctl start slapd
```

But it fails with:

```
main: TLS init def ctx failed: -1
```

I really do not understand it because I removed everything and it started smoothly when I installled it the first time. I have not set up TLS.

Update:

I made it run with the following changes. I do not know if they will persist

/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif

```
#olcTLSCACertificatePath: /etc/openldap/certs
#olcTLSCertificateFile: "OpenLDAP Server"
#olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/password
```

Comment: Does dmesg report any SELinux "AVC" failures?

Comment: No, grep found nothing